# OrientDB (2.0.4) custom serializer

Tags: java, orientdb

while playing around with OrientDB 2.0.4 I encountered the following problem:

I have the following classes

```
public class ClassA{

    private String someData;
    private ClassB embeddedClass;

}

public class ClassB implements Serializable{

    private Integer someData;
    private ClassC classToBeReferenced;

}

public class ClassC implements Serializable{

    private Boolean someData;
}
```

Allthough ClassC should not be embedded in ClassB, ClassB contains an actual instance of ClassC so that people can easily set an instance of ClassC on ClassB (and not have to deal with OrientDB to get the RID of the instance of ClassC).

The problem with this setup is that OrientDB embeds ClassC in ClassB when an instance of ClassB is serialized. In order to avoid that I created a custom serializer for ClassC:

```
public class ClassCSerializer implements OObjectSerializer<ClassC, ORID> {

    ....

}
```

My problem is now, that I cannot find any method to register the serializer anywhere. The tutorial where I found the solution with the custom implementation of OObjectSerializer said that the serializer should be registered at an OObjectSerializerContext. However, I cannot find the class on the classpath. I have orient-core, -client and -enterprise modules in version 2.0.4 on my classpath.

Can anybody help me out here?

Regards,
Pascal

Comment: Ref: https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Object-2-Record-Java-Binding.html

Comment: Or for 2.0: https://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Object-2-Record-Java-Binding.html

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know about 2.0.4, but for 2.0.10 OObjectSerializerContext is in the orientdb-object-2.0.10.jar jar.

I found an example of how to use it here:
https://code.google.com/p/orient/issues/detail?id=299

```
OObjectSerializerContext serializerContext = new OObjectSerializerContext();
serializerContext.bind(new OObjectSerializer<DateTime, Long>() {

public Long serializeFieldValue(Object iPojo, String iFieldName, DateTime iFieldValue)
{
    return iFieldValue.getMillis();
}

public DateTime unserializeFieldValue(Object iPojo, String iFieldName, Long iFieldValue)
{
    return new DateTime(iFieldValue);
}

});
OObjectSerializerHelper.bindSerializerContext(null, serializerContext);
```